# Cloth is going through the collided ball

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, collision

I want to create an animation that, when the ball collied with the curtain, the curtain should shake a realistic way but in my animation, the curtain goes along with the ball, and it's very unrealistic. I have tried so many things. But couldn't get a good result. Give me help with this scenario.

This is what I get,

[image]

For the ball, I added Collision physics and for the curtain, I added Cloth physics as well as subdivision surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertexes in the curtain are getting stuck inside the ball--You'll want to increase the collision distance:
[image]

Comment: Is this distance enough or can we increase the distance further?

Comment: I increased the distance and now the cloth is not coming through the ball but the behavior of the cloth is very unrealistic after the ball gets hits. D I need to bake cloth and ball?