# Why is this object not colliding with a cloth?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I am trying to make a plastic bag with

Why is this blender cube with:

- A collision modifier with single-sided disabled

Not colliding with this cloth with:

- Object collisions enabled
- A thickness

Here you can see it phasing through the bag around the edge:

[image: Phasing]

I have tried:

- [Why is the mesh not colliding with cloth simulation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213055/why-is-the-mesh-not-colliding-with-cloth-simulation) (N/A, not a softbody)
- [Is there a way to make rigid body interact with softbody physics?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96744/is-there-a-way-to-make-rigid-body-interact-with-softbody-physics) (N/A, not a softbody)
- [Collision issue in cloth simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298552/collision-issue-in-cloth-simulation)
- [Cloth is going through the collided ball](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209134/cloth-is-going-through-the-collided-ball)
- [cloth sim refuses to respond to any and all collision objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248218/cloth-sim-refuses-to-respond-to-any-and-all-collision-objects)

[image]

Comment: The file crashes when trying to open it (in versions 2.8, 3.5, and 4.0). Can you try the file you uploaded and reupload it if it fails for you as well? What version are you using?

Comment: @Joachim I can open it, maybe append the objects in a new file?

Comment: @moonboots If I append anything, it crashes, too. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible at the moment. Rigid body and cloth are different type of simulations that doesn't affect each other. Should be a task for future realizes of blender geometry nodes, then simulation nodes can be used for such connections between simulation types.

Comment: actually you can assign both Rigid Body and Collision to the same object, the problem is that in his case the object continues to go through at a certain point, not sure if some parameters allow to prevent that